Making a battery power supply for a portable Raspberry Pi computer
I am trying to make a portable Raspberry Pi computer, the idea is just a Pi, a screen that is powered through the Pi, a keyboard and battery power. I have been trying to figure out how one would actually make such an integrated power solution and I have six 18650 cells.
If I simply run them in parallel and have cheap charging circuit from Amazon and a buck converter run in series is with the battery pack is that sufficient? how are these things normally designed?
I don't have much experience in smaller electronics as I normally work with 24 V to 230 V systems.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Why roll your own solution? Why not use a power bank, or buy one of the several available Raspberry Pi battery "hats" for it?

I my experience powerbanks just gets me under voltage errors and i have yet to find a raspberry pi HAT that lasts as long as i want or has the specs i need.

@jeppe1900 An RPi is power hungry. It will never last very long on batteries. Add a screen to that, and it's even worse. What RPI model? What screen (brand, model, size, connection to the Pi, backlight...)? What other peripherals? How long do you expect it to run? What are "the specs you need"? Your batteries will yield at best 6 x 3400 mAh * 3.7 V / 5 V = 15 Ah, probably a lot less. An Rpi alone can use over 1 A.

You're right, the RPI4 is quite power hungry. and i dont expect this to be a perfect solution, but learning the basics of this is probably my best bet at making something better for my projects.


I don't have much experience in smaller electronics

I strongly recommend that you incorporate an off-the-shelf power bank instead of spinning your own: a commercial product is safe, guaranteed to work, properly enclosed, solves problems you haven't even thought of, and meets regulations.
That notwithstanding, to answer your questions:

You also need a single-cell protector BMS between the cells and the rest of the circuit.
The input of the buck converter between the battery and the load is in parallel with the battery, not in series.


"an off-the-shelf power bank ...  meets regulations."  Well, hopefully it does...

Thank you. i am trying to learn this stuff but its pretty hard. Do you know any guides or things to read up on to understand this? better than coming back here constantly and asking noob questions.

@jeppe1900 Try the Wiki in AskElectronics. I recommend this book.
